# OpenGL object lighting messed up

Tags: opengl, lighting

I made a set of objects that are animated and move around the screen. The animation looks fine, but I'm having issues with the material settings. The lighting on the sphere looks very bizarre. A frame:

[image: frame]

So those colours on the sphere, I have no idea where they came from. It's meant to be copper/brass, can't remember now, but it sure isn't... I'll post the whole code because I have no idea where the problem might lie. I apologise for how messy it is.

```
package a3;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.gl2.GLUT;

import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class Animation3 extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {
private float[] amb = new float[]{0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0f};
private float[] dif = new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, 0f};
private float outerTorusDepth = 0.0f;
private float torusRotatingAngle = 0.01f;
private float delta = 0.01f;
private float s = 0f;
private float angle1 = 0f;
private float radius = 0.2f;
private float height = 0.3f;
private float deltaR = 0.001f;
private float deltaH = 0.001f;

private float alpha = 0f;

private static final float R = 1.0f; // radius of rotation around z axis
private static final float R2 = 2f; // radius of rotation around z axis

private GLU glu;
private GLUT glut;
private GLCanvas canvas;

public Animation3() {
    super("Animation");

    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.getDefault());
    canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);
    canvas.addGLEventListener(this);

    getContentPane().add(canvas);
}

public void run() {
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    canvas.requestFocusInWindow();

    Animator animator = new Animator();
    animator.add(canvas);
    animator.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Animation3().run();
}

public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    glu = new GLU();
    glut = new GLUT();

    drawable.getGL().setSwapInterval(1);

    initLighting(drawable);

    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_CULL_FACE);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    glu.gluPerspective(40f, 1f, 1f, 20f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 5,
            0, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0);
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    update();

    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT1);
    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_LIGHT2);
    amb[3] = dif[3] = (float) (0.5 - Math.cos(s * .95) / 2);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, FloatBuffer.wrap(amb));
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(dif));

    alpha += 0.001;
    float tx = (float) (R * Math.cos(alpha));
    float ty = (float) (R * Math.sin(alpha));
    float tx2 = (float) (R2 * Math.cos(alpha));
    float ty2 = (float) (R2 * Math.sin(alpha));



    gl.glPushMatrix();

    gl.glTranslatef(tx, ty, outerTorusDepth);
    gl.glRotatef(torusRotatingAngle,-torusRotatingAngle,torusRotatingAngle*2, 5f);
    gl.glScalef(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);

    float[] mat_ambient3 ={ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
    float[] mat_diffuse3 ={ 0.1f,0.35f,0.1f,1.0f};
    float[] mat_specular3 ={0.45f,0.55f,0.45f,1.0f };
    float shine = 32.0f ;
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_SPECULAR, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_ambient3));
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_diffuse3));
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_AMBIENT, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_specular3));
    gl.glMaterialf(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_SHININESS, shine);

    glut.glutSolidDodecahedron();

    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glPushMatrix();

    gl.glTranslatef(tx, ty, outerTorusDepth);
    gl.glRotatef(torusRotatingAngle,1f,2f, 5f);
    gl.glScalef(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    gl.glTranslatef(tx2, ty2, outerTorusDepth);

    float[] mat_ambient ={ 0.2295f, 0.08825f, 0.0275f, 1.0f };
    float[] mat_diffuse ={0.5508f, 0.2118f, 0.066f, 1.0f };
    float[] mat_specular ={0.580594f, 0.223257f, 0.0695701f, 1.0f };
    shine =51.2f ;
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_SPECULAR, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_ambient));
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_diffuse));
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_AMBIENT, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_specular));
    gl.glMaterialf(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_SHININESS, shine);

    glut.glutSolidSphere(0.4f, 100, 100);

    gl.glPopMatrix();




    gl.glPushMatrix();

    gl.glTranslatef(tx, ty, outerTorusDepth);
    gl.glRotatef(torusRotatingAngle, 5f, -torusRotatingAngle, 5f);

    float[] mat_ambient2 ={ 0.1f, 0.18725f, 0.1745f, 0.8f };
    float[] mat_diffuse2 ={0.396f, 0.74151f, 0.69102f, 0.8f };
    float[] mat_specular2 ={0.297254f, 0.30829f, 0.306678f, 0.8f };
    shine = 12.8f;
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_SPECULAR, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_ambient2));
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_diffuse2));
    gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_AMBIENT, FloatBuffer.wrap(mat_specular2));
    gl.glMaterialf(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_SHININESS, shine);

    glut.glutSolidTorus(0.1f, 0.5f, 100, 100);

    gl.glPopMatrix();


    gl.glPushAttrib(GL2.GL_ENABLE_BIT);
    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluOrtho2D(0, 1500, 0, 1500);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glPopAttrib();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

private void update() {
    angle1 = (angle1 + 1.1f) % 360f;
    s += 0.05;
    if (outerTorusDepth >= 2.0f || outerTorusDepth <= -2.0f) 
        delta = -delta;
    outerTorusDepth += delta;
    torusRotatingAngle = (torusRotatingAngle + 2.5f) % 360f;


    if (radius > 0.3f || radius < 0.1f)
        deltaR = -deltaR;
    if (height > 0.35f || height < 0.15f)
        deltaH = -deltaH;
    radius += deltaR;
    height += deltaH;
}

private static final float[] LIGHT0_AMBIENT = new float[]{0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f};
private static final float[] LIGHT_0_DIFFUSE = new float[]{0f, 0f, 0f, 1f};

private static final float[] LIGHT1_DIFFUSE = new float[]{1f, 0f, 0f, 1f};
private static final float[] LIGHT1_POSITION = new float[]{5f, 1f, 1f, 0f};

private static final float[] LIGHT2_DIFFUSE = new float[]{0f, 0f, 1f, 1f};
private static final float[] LIGHT2_POSITION = new float[]{-10f, 1f, 1f, 0f};

private static void initLighting(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
    GL2 gl2 = glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT0);

    gl2.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, FloatBuffer.wrap(LIGHT0_AMBIENT));
    gl2.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(LIGHT_0_DIFFUSE));
    //
            gl2.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(LIGHT1_DIFFUSE));
            gl2.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_POSITION, FloatBuffer.wrap(LIGHT1_POSITION));
    //
            gl2.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT2, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(LIGHT2_DIFFUSE));
            gl2.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT2, GL2.GL_POSITION, FloatBuffer.wrap(LIGHT2_POSITION));
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
}

public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure where the problem might be, but you have a lot of ambient light there - `{0.8,0.8,0.8}` is almost full light, which will make it difficult to see the effects of the other light. You might also want to change glLightModel to "local viewer". Or, even better, stop using the long-deprecated immediate mode.

Comment: You also have the ambient and specular values exchanged in all the `glMaterialfv()` calls.